# Why In while loop user_number not doing check with areEquals method?

Tags: java

While loop not working and dont check with areEquals method new inputs not taking in consideration why?

```
do {
    try {

        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Number : ");
        user_number = number.nextInt();
        String temp = Integer.toString(user_number);
        int[] array = new int[temp.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            array[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        }

        while (!areEquals(array)) {
            System.out.println("Repeated numbers are not allowed");
            System.out.print("Number : ");                 
            user_number = number.nextInt();
        }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Only integer numbers are allowed !");
            ok = false;
        } 
} while (!ok);
```

Comment: What's the implementation of `areEquals`? Where is the declaration and definition of `ok`, i.e. what's the initial value?

Comment: Can you be more clear to describe the problem?

Comment: Echoing Lothar, could you provide more of your code? Like at least your areEquals method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're actually asking but

```
        while (!areEquals(array)){
            System.out.println("Repeated numbers are not allowed");
            System.out.print("Number : ");
            user_number = number.nextInt();
        }
```

will lead to an infinite loop if `areEquals` returns `false` because you never create a new array from the new input and therefor passing the first value being entered over and over again.